# icon distribution packaging

Tags: icons, package, distribute

i need you help guys. I have designed numerouse icons.

I need to package them for sale into these categories Normal, Hot, Disabled, Gray and these size 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 128x128, 256x256.

Do you know any software that can do this automatically for me, or do i have to develop my own.

Am average programmer in vb.net. But not an expert in graphics programming.

please give you suggestions

Comment: do you want the software to sort the icons automatically by size and category? or what is it exactly that you want it to do?

Comment: yes if i could get that too, it would be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a random [site](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/03/06/35-really-incredible-free-icon-sets/) or [two](http://www.tutorial9.net/resources/cute-critters-free-icon-pack/) it seems like good old PKZIP is the standard way of distributing them.

Comment: i was not looking for icons, but software to package them into different size and different colors. The zip software is not what i really need